# "getaddrinfo failed", what does that mean?

Tags: python, bottle

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)   gaierror: [Errno 11004]
getaddrinfo failed
```

Getting this error when launching the hello world sample from here:

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

Comment: Is there a way to gracefully handle this error?  I have a password reset form and it works fine if the `EMAIL_HOST` info is correct.  But assuming that the e-mail server is down for some reason, how do I handle this case?  It's all done under the covers by the `django.contrib.auth()` modules right now.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It most likely means the hostname can't be resolved.

```
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 8080)
```

If it doesn't work there, it's not going to work in the Bottle example.  You can try '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' in case that's the problem.

Comment: Remmeber to put the quotes:
socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080)

Answer (score 18):

The problem, in my case, was that some install at some point defined an environment variable **http_proxy** on my machine when I had no proxy.

Removing the **http_proxy** environment variable fixed the problem.

Comment: Notebook at work: everything great. Notebook at home: Failed. I set this environment variable a long time ago and forgot about it. I wonder why python's http library doesn't get proxy settings from the OS... BTW I was getting this error with `easy_install`

Answer (score 7):

The problem in my case was that I needed to *add* environment variables for `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

E.g.,

```
http_proxy=http://your_proxy:your_port
https_proxy=https://your_proxy:your_port
```

To set these environment variables in Windows, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059670/how-to-set-proxy-for-command-prompt).

Answer (score 6):

I spent some good hours fixing this but the solution turned out to be really simple. I had my ftp server address starting with `ftp://`. I removed it and the code started working.

FTP address before:

```
ftp_css_address = "ftp://science-xyz.xyz.xyz.int"
```

Changed it to:

```
ftp_css_address = "science-xyz.xyz.xyz.int"
```

Comment: Same for me, except I had to remove `http://` , and change the class `http.client.HTTPSConnection` to `http.client.HTTPConnection` . I have only tried this with `localhost:8000`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you pass a proxy attribute in your command
forexample - pip install --proxy=http://proxyhost:proxyport pixiedust

Use a proxy port which has direct connection (with / without password). Speak with your corporate IT administrator. Quick way is find out network settings used in eclipse which will have direct connection.

You will encouter this issue often if you work behind a corporate firewall. You will have to check your internet explorer - InternetOptions -LAN Connection - Settings

Uncheck - Use automatic configuration script
Check - Use a proxy server for your LAN. Ensure you have given the right address and port.

Click Ok
Come back to anaconda terminal and you can try install commands

Answer (score 4):

May be this will help some one. I have my proxy setup in python script but keep getting the error mentioned in the question.

Below is the piece of block which will take my username and password as a constant in the beginning.

```
   if (use_proxy):
        proxy = req.ProxyHandler({'https': proxy_url})
        auth = req.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
        opener = req.build_opener(proxy, auth, req.HTTPHandler)
        req.install_opener(opener)
```

If you are using corporate laptop and if you did not connect to Direct Access or office VPN then the above block will throw error. All you need to do is to connect to your org VPN and then execute your python script.

Thanks