# Python resolve a host name with IPv6 address

Tags: python, dns, ipv6

I wonder if there is a way to use python to resolve a hostname that resolves only in ipv6 and/or for a hostname that resolves both in ipv4 and ipv6?

`socket.gethostbyname()` and `socket.gethostbyname_ex()`does not work for ipv6 resolution.

A dummy way to do that is to run actual linux host command and parse the results. Is there any better way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[socket.getaddrinfo](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) supports IPv6. You just need to set `family` to `AF_INET6`.

```
socket.getaddrinfo("example.com", None, socket.AF_INET6)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but not with the format you mentioned. It doesn't take any keyword argument.

Comment: With socket.AF_INET6, this returns only local IPV6 for my Win10. without param AF_INET6, it  returns also public IPV6 and IPV4

Comment: I tried this for "www.google.com" and it returns an error `[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed` but when use `nslookup -query=AAAA google.com` it returns some IPv6 address. Is there any way to get same IPv6 address by using the python script?

Answer (score 3):

**I want to expand on the answer of @john-colanduoni with more detail.**

## Get only the IPv6 address

To really get *only* the corresponding IPv6-address, you should try using [socket.getaddrinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo).

```
>>> print(socket.getaddrinfo('www.microsoft.com', None, socket.AF_INET6)[0][4][0])
2a02:26f0:6a:288::356e
```

but beware, e.g. if there is no IPv6 AAAA-Record for the hostname, such as:

```
>>> print(socket.getaddrinfo('microsoft.com', None, socket.AF_INET6)[0][4][0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

you will get `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` which is a subclass of [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html#socket.gaierror).

Btw. try using `localhost`, the `hostname` of your computer (if it's IPv6 enabled) or `example.com` as the hostname argument.

## Get the hostname from IPv6 address

A query for the PTR-Record would look like:

```
>>> print(socket.gethostbyaddr('2a00:1450:4001:81d::200e')[0])
fra15s18-in-x0e.1e100.net
```

since [socket.gethostbyaddr](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr) is both IPv4 and IPv6 enabled.

Comment: Did not work for me, returned an error `[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`

Comment: @Sachihiro can you be more specific? Maybe you have to `import socket` first? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean

Comment: Yea of course i imported socket, It would be a different error if I had not done that. I think it is a bug on python 3.9, updated to 3.9.2 and the error persists.

Comment: @Sachihiro what OS is this? Does your resolver actually deliver IPv6 AAAA records (try with nslookup, host, dig or other tools depending on platform)?
What have you found by searching for the bug on the web? Have you found, where this messsage gets emitted in the source code of Python or elsewhere?
I use Python 3.9.1 on Debian and it doesn't hit this error.

Comment: I am on Windows, and yes I used nslookup, tried on `google.com`