# How to get hostname from an IPv6 address in Python using socket.gethostbyaddr

Tags: python, ip, ipv6, hostname, gethostbyaddr

I am currently trying to get host information from a user's IP address. I need my program to work with both IPv6 and IPv4. My understanding is that socket.gethostbyaddr(my_ip) should work with both IPv6 and IPv4, but with my code:

```
host_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(my_ip)
```

I just get the following error:

```
socket.herror: [Errno 11004] host not found
```

It works with IPv4 addresses though, and the IPv6 address I'm using works in all other parts of my program. What gives? I've looked around and found this user [Python resolve a host name with IPv6 address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373288/python-resolve-a-host-name-with-ipv6-address) had the same issue but it doesn't look like it was ever resolved.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Are you using a link-local address? That requires a Zone ID.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't actually know. Honestly I just Googled "What is my IP address?" and copied the result for my public IP address gave me.

Comment: If you mean getting your WAN address, then you probably do not have a DNS entry from which you can resolve the name.