# (python) [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, getaddrinfo

Can someone help me on how I can catch this error?

```
import pygeoip  
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIP.dat')  
print gi.country_code_by_name('specificdownload.com')  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<module1>", line 14, in <module>  
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pygeoip\__init__.py", line 447, in country_code_by_name  
    addr = self._gethostbyname(hostname)  
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pygeoip\__init__.py", line 392, in _gethostbyname  
    return socket.gethostbyname(hostname)  
gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["getaddrinfo failed", what does that mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: You should add a bit more context to this question. What is the code for, and which platform your are trying it on, at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let’s ask Python what type of exception that is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import pygeoip
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIP.dat')
try:
    print gi.country_code_by_name('specificdownload.com')
except Exception, e:
    print type(e)
    print e
```

Prints:

```
$ ./foo.py
<class 'socket.gaierror'>
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

So we need to catch `socket.gaierror`, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import pygeoip
import socket
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIP.dat')
try:
    print gi.country_code_by_name('specificdownload.com')
except socket.gaierror:
    print 'ignoring failed address lookup'
```

Though there’s still the question of, what the heck is `gaierror`? Google turns up [the `socket.gaierror` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gaierror), which says,

> This exception is raised for address-related errors, for `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`

So GAI Error = Get Address Info Error.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The code attempts to access a server which cannot be reached, perhaps because you are not connected to the public Internet, or perhaps because it no longer exists. A snippet out of the implicated `__init__.py` file should help clarify this.

Comment: how can we get addr info ?