# i have face this error Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Tags: php

### my error is

`

```
 if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="server"  )
{ 
// Config setting for localhost.
define("DBSERVER","localhost");
define("DBNAME","raj12");
define("DBUSER","root");
define("DBPASS","");   
$connect=   mysql_connect("DBSERVER","DBUSER","DBPASS") or die(mysql_error()."cannot             connect local");

} 
else
{ // Config setting for live server.
define(DBSERVER,"localhost");
define(DBNAME,"raj12");
define(DBUSER,"root@123");
define(DBPASS,"root@123");
mysql_connect(DBSERVER,DBUSER,DBPASS) or die("cannot connect server");

}

mysql_select_db(DBNAME)or die("error in selecting database");
include("db.class.php");
$obj=new DB(DBNAME,DBSERVER,DBUSER,DBPASS);

?>`
```

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\rajsons\lib\config.php on line 14##

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="server"  )
{ 
    // Config setting for localhost.
    define(DBSERVER, "localhost");
    define(DBNAME, "raj12");
    define(DBUSER, "root");
    define(DBPASS, "");   
    $connect = mysql_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS) or die(mysql_error() . "cannot connect local");
}
```

And better to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`

Comment: Why would indenting the define statements help? (Answers should explain the solution and not be games of spot-the-difference).

Comment: I edited my answer :) and added some suggestion also.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing string literals instead of the constants you defined.

```
mysql_connect("DBSERVER","DBUSER","DBPASS")
```

Remove the quotes.