# error installing nltk supporting packages : nltk.download() in python

Tags: python, nlp

I installed `nltk package`. Following that I am trying to download the supporting packages using `nltk.download()` and am getting error:

```
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo
```

I tried changing server index as suggested by [previous answers for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Yii.png) but that didn't help me.

Can anyone please help me

Comment: Have you read this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750608/error-installing-nltk-supporting-packages-nltk-download?rq=1 ?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? You need to set a proxy to pass through.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor  for your help , setting proxy solved error

Answer (score 0):

Setting proxy solved my problem.