# Setting up ntlk proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, nltk-book

I was following  first chapter of the [nltk book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html#frequency-distributions). It asks us to install book corpus by running `nltk.dowwnload()`.

I am getting `getattrinfo failed` error while doing `ntlk.download()`. After reading online, I came to know that this has something to do with my proxy.

[image]

So I tried setting proxies in different ways (trying `http` or `https`, `%40` or `@` in password):

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080',('123456','password%40123'))
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080',('123456','password@123'))
nltk.set_proxy('https://proxy.mycompany.com:8080',('123456','password%40123'))
nltk.set_proxy('https://proxy.mycompany.com:8080',('123456','password@123'))
```

(I was able to succesfully set proxy for `pip` and install `nltk`, but not sure if I am making mistake in case of `nltk` proxy)

Then I also tried

```
C:\Users\123456>python -m nltk.downloader all
[nltk_data] Error loading all: <urlopen error [Errno 11004]
[nltk_data]     getaddrinfo failed>
Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]
```

Next I tried

```
>>>nltk.download('book')
```

But this too gives same error:

```
>>> nltk.download('book')
[nltk_data] Error loading book: <urlopen error [Errno 11004]
[nltk_data]     getaddrinfo failed>
```

Then I also tried by changing server index url as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764910/1317018), but no use. Also the [pre populated index is alive](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml) (and I am able to open it in the browser), so I guess I need not change server index url.

Comment: The precise URL you are attempting to access and the diagnostics to suggest that the problem is proxy-related would be good to include in the question. It's not impossible that the problem is a combination of two things, or that the proxy is *also* a problem but that you have another problem which we cannot see from the details you currently provide.

Comment: Also, where exactly are you entering this proxy configuration, and how does it apply to the `python -m` scenario?

Comment: I am executing `nltk.download()` command on python command prompt. Also it seems that the call to `download()` tries to access [this url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml), which is already included in the problem. `nltk.set_proxy()` is also executed on python command prompt. It has to be executed on python command prompt only, right?

Comment: Is there any firewall blocking your machine to download any files from the internet (not nltk)? Do a `wget https://norvig.com/big.txt` on the terminal, did it successfully download?

Comment: @alvas I am able to open that link in browser. BTW I am on Windows 7, not on any *nix machine

Comment: You have to download the file through the command prompt to check if some thing is blocking you. Also, see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: After you've installed as the github gist instruction, in powershell python, `import nltk; nltk.download('popular')`

Comment: I dont have admin privileges on this machine. So I guess installing anaconda is possible. Seems that instructions [here](https://medium.com/@satorulogic/how-to-manually-download-a-nltk-corpus-f01569861da9) are working. I tried downloading several corpora (inaugural, gutenberg etc) from [here](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) and putting them in folder `D:\nltk_data\corpora` and them using them.  But same is not working with `punkt` corpora. It seems that unlike other corpora, which contained text, `punkt` contains pickle files. How do I import it?