# Dealing with pickel files in nltk corpora

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, pickle

I am trying out [nltk tutorial](http://www.nltk.org/book/).

The [problem I was facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130879/setting-up-ntlk-proxy) was that it requires to download various corpora. After all solutions failed to solve the problem I was facing to download nltk corpora with `nltk.download()`, I resorted to steps stated [here](https://medium.com/@satorulogic/how-to-manually-download-a-nltk-corpus-f01569861da9).

I started downloading corpora required for any example from [this page](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/), putting it in directory `D:\nltk_data\corpora`. I was able to try out various example. But then at one example I got error :

```
 Resource punkt not found.
 Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

 >>> import nltk
 >>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

So I downloaded punkt from same page and copy pasted in same above directory. But it did not worked. Also tried to do `from nltk.corpus import punkt` as in case of other corpora. But no use. It says `Unresolved import: punkt`

One difference in punkt from other corpora is that it contains pickle  files instead of text files as in case of other corpora. How should I fix this?

**Code:**

```
import nltk;

from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

for fileid in gutenberg.fileids():
    num_chars = len(gutenberg.raw(fileid)) 
    num_words = len(gutenberg.words(fileid))
    num_sents = len(gutenberg.sents(fileid))
    num_vocab = len(set(w.lower() for w in gutenberg.words(fileid)))
    print(round(num_chars/num_words), round(num_words/num_sents), round(num_words/num_vocab), fileid)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mahesh\workspaces\pyworkspace\nltkdemo\chp2\chp2.py", line 8, in <module>
    num_sents = len(gutenberg.sents(fileid))
  File "D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 233, in __len__
    for tok in self.iterate_from(self._toknum[-1]): pass
  File "D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 296, in iterate_from
    tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
  File "D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\nltk\corpus\reader\plaintext.py", line 129, in _read_sent_block
    for sent in self._sent_tokenizer.tokenize(para)])
  File "D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\nltk\data.py", line 984, in __getattr__
    self.__load()
  File "D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\nltk\data.py", line 976, in __load
    resource = load(self._path)
  File "D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\nltk\data.py", line 836, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\nltk\data.py", line 954, in _open
    return find(path_, path + ['']).open()
  File "D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\nltk\data.py", line 675, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource [93mpunkt[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  [31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  [0m
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\593932/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\share\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\Softwares\\python\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\Mahesha999\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

The error seem to happen at line 8: `num_sents = len(gutenberg.sents(fileid))`

Comment: Can you please update the question with actual code that is giving the error

Comment: The correct path for punkt folder is "nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt" . Try to put the folder in that path and try again.

Comment: @Sam tried, rest of corpora is at `D:\nltk_data\corpora\`, `punkt` is at `D:\nltk_data\corpora\tokenizers`, not working...

Comment: @Sam put the same in `D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\nltk_data` and `D:\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\nltk_data\tokenizers`, it started working!!!

Comment: @Mahesha999 : not D:\nltk_data\corpora\tokenizers but nltk_data/tokenizers/ path . corpora and tokenizers are two different folders inside nltk_data.

Comment: yup done... thanks for correcting me. One more thing. How this gutenberg works? If I delete `nltk_data\corpora\gutenberg`, it does not work. When kept, it works. But I was guessing how I am able to call `.raw()`, `words()` on it. `print(gutenberg)` prints `<PlaintextCorpusReader in 'D:\\nltk_data\\corpora\\gutenberg'>`. So importing gutenberg imports `PlaintextCorpusReader`!! I am not able to understand this. How this import is behaving exactly? Cause there is not `PlaintextCorpusReader` on that path `D:\\nltk_data\\corpora\\gutenberg'>`

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data

Comment: Download with `nltk.download('punkt')` and don't move anything. The NLTK package will automatically find it.

Comment: Yes I know that, I already tried that and [had lots of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130879/setting-up-ntlk-proxy) as stated in the question? I will be happy if you resolve that too.