# Not able to install nltk supporting packages and getting noaddrinfo error with nltk.download()

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

After importing nltk to my system i tried to download the packages using nltk.download()
but its showing the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miexq.png)

i have tried changing the proxy but its not working(my laptop is not using any proxy but it is connected to VPN).
I tried to manually download required packages from http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ but still not going anywhere.
i also tried
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMqn.png)

and
i have tried every solution from
[error installing nltk supporting packages : nltk.download()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750608/error-installing-nltk-supporting-packages-nltk-download)
,but the problem remains the same.