# Can't connect Abaqus PDE to Abaqus/CAE

Tags: python, abaqus

When I try to run Abaqus PDE (Python development environment) for example from the windows command line with the command:

```
abaqus cae -pde
```

I get the following error in the command line:

```py
pde:atxGuiSvr.ipcSvrStart(start=1,atxCaePort=51422):class'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

and Abaqus PDE can't connect to the Abaqus/CAE. Therefore when I try to run a python script in APDE (in Kernel) I get the following error in the APDE:

```
Spawn: abq6144 cae -rt d:/ABQ_Temp/postProc.py  
*** Error - remote process did not start  
Exit from main file  [Kernel]: d:/ABQ_Temp/IBDiM_DK1_2017/postProc.py
```

and in the command line

```
Abaqus Error: Invalid command line option: The "-atxPort (atxPort=)" argument required a port number.
```

My OS is Windows 10. I thought the problem might have been related to the firewall settings so I tried deactivating firewall but it didn't help.

How to solve this? I'd like to fix PDE integration with Abaqus/CAE because I want to use the PDE debugger.

Comment: Sounds like an installation problem. can you start it with `abaqus pde` ?  Can you start it from the cae file menu?

Comment: Yes. When I start PDE with `abaqus pde`, the PDE can't launch Abaqus/CAE either. When I start PDE from Abaqus/CAE file menu, I get the same error as I wrote in my post. It's also worth mentioning that running cmd.exe with administrator privileges doesn't help. I think the problem might be similar to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean). Maybe changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" would solve to problem, but I couldn't find any configuration files for Abaqus PDE.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you installed (or tried to install) a cracked version of Abaqus in the past. When you do so, you modify the way sockets created by Abaqus access the DNS service (so that the license isn't checked), and these changes also affect sockets that connect different programs within Abaqus. (In this case Abaqus/PDE and Abaqus/CAE.) That's why you get that "getaddrinfo failed" message. (getaddrinfo is a function of the Python module socket.)

What I did to solve this issue was to uninstall the version of Abaqus I had, restart my computer in safe mode, delete the folder C:\SIMULIA, restart again in normal mode and install my version of Abaqus again. I have to say that PDE will never connect to CAE if you use a cracked version of Abaqus.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your temp path if there are abaqus commands. Also You can try re install abaqus.

You can also write these lines in your script then can try again. It will work.

```
#
from part import *
from material import *
from section import *
from optimization import *
from assembly import *
from step import *
from interaction import *
from load import *
from mesh import *
from job import *
from sketch import *
from visualization import *
from connectorBehavior import *
import __main__
import section
import regionToolset
import displayGroupMdbToolset as dgm
import part
import material
import assembly
import step
import interaction
import load
import mesh
import job
import sketch
import visualization
import xyPlot
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo
import connectorBehavior
import odbAccess
#
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=None)
#
```