# Max retries exceeded with url REST Python

Tags: python, rest, post

I am performing a REST post request using python code. I am trying to communicate with an external server. I am performing several REST calls but a specific one fails. That specific request is the following:

```
 r = requests.post(url, json=item[1], headers=headers)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='....euapi', port= ...): 
Max retries exceeded with url: ...(Caused by NewConnectionError
('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at: ... 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

It seems that the server is blocking the connection to me because of the number of connction with it. However, I just perform only one call. Does that make sense? Any idea of how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: is this some kind of external REST API provider?

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned that. Yes trying to communicate with external sever.

Comment: Doesn't have a requests count limit? Anything in their documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your 'url' value is not correct (address cannot be resolved). Please check it carefully

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean)