# Old Noob Python 3.6 FTP mystery error msg

Tags: python

Using Python 3.6
successfully retrieving data from mssqlserver and querying oracle for historical data and exporting it via Pandas to a tab delimited file which I then want to be able to ftp to another mssql server location.  Since I have not tried this before, I experimented as follows:

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
 This works:  passing hardcoded variable
 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
from ftplib import FTP

host='myserver'
host_name='group_user_name'
host_pw='hostpassword'
host_dir='myworkingdirectory'

ftp = FTP(host)
ftp.login(user=host_name, passwd =host_pw)
ftp.cwd(host_dir)

filename = 'c:/temp/cigfun.txt'
fn = 'cigfun.txt' 

def placeFile():
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+fn, open(filename, 'rb'))
    ftp.quit()

placeFile()
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
This also works:  hard coded
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('myserver')
ftp.login(user='group_user_name', passwd ='hostpassword')
ftp.cwd('myworkingdirectory')
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

This does not connect:  retrieving data from stored procedure in MSSQL

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
if sql_id == str(5): 
        sql_cursor.execute("[dbo].[usp_GetProcess_"+seq_action+"] @sql_id = "+ sql_id)
        table = sql_cursor.fetchall()
        for row in table:
            host = "'"+row[1]+"'"
            host_name = "'"+row[2]+"'"
            host_pw = "'"+row[3]+"'"
            host_dir = "'"+row[4]+"'"
            host_dir = re.sub('[cd ]', '', host_dir)
            ftp_file = row[9]
            f_type = row[10]
            if f_type == "Tab (txt)":
                f_type = '.txt'
            elif f_type == "Comma (csv)":
                f_type = '.csv'
            else: f_type = '.xlsx'

            path_file = "'"+ftp_file + f_type+"'"
            fn="'"+os.path.basename(path_file)
            path_file = path_file.replace(r'\\','/')

            from ftplib import FTP
            ftp = FTP(host)
            ftp.login(user = host_name, passwd = host_pw)
            ftp.cwd(host_dir)
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
throws the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\A22021\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda332\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

aside from my awkward efforts at coding (only my 3rd production attempt using Python), can you see anything obvious that would cause the failure?  error messages are so cryptic.
I suspect it might have something to do with coded variable assignments, but I am baffled right now.  Any constructive advice appreciated.
PLG

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["getaddrinfo failed", what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean)

Answer (score 0):

If everything works when you hard-code the FTP information, then the issue here is most likely the way you are parsing the query results. You need to see exactly what is getting put into your `host*` variables. To start, you could just pepper your code with some print statements, but I would highly suggest using the python debugger instead. This probably sounds scary, but it's not that bad. Run it like this:

```
python -m pdb my_script.py
```

You can then step through each line of your code by pressing `n`. So for example, when you hit the line that says `for row in table:` and you press `n` you will now be inside that loop and can `print(row)`. This will give you some insight into what is going wrong with the parsing.