# How do I programmatically download my bank transactions from Chase without using a third party?

Tags: ofx

I'm interested in downloading my transactions from Chase without using a third party such as Mint, Quicken, Yodlee, Plaid, and so on. I don't trust third parties with handling my data, which is why I want to do it myself.

Answer (score 23):

Works as of 1/8/18

### Summary

Chase uses OFX to support programmatic interactions with its financial data. It does so somewhat reluctantly however, as this fact isn't widely advertised nor well documented - banks would rather have you use their products directly, rather than go to third parties. That being said, support for desktop products like Quicken still exists, and so one method is to spoof yourself as a desktop product (the other options are to use a third party service or use a screen scraper). Obviously this solution is completely at the mercy of Chase's whims, and as a discouraged access pattern this is not robust. But you're still reading, so let's do this!

### Solution

1. Set up your account to accept connections from Desktop apps
   Account > Profile & Settings > Manage Account Security > Desktop apps > Click enable
2. Generate a Client UID. Chase will use this to verify that the OFX requests it's receiving are intended.
   Go to https://www.uuidgenerator.net/ and generate a UID.
3. Use [ofx-ba-tfb.py](https://github.com/agtsai-i/ofx) to POST the following to https://ofx.chase.com. Comments begin with a # sign, do not include them.

Headers:

```
OFXHEADER:100
DATA:OFXSGML
VERSION:102
SECURITY:NONE
ENCODING:USASCII
CHARSET:1252
COMPRESSION:NONE
OLDFILEUID:NONE
NEWFILEUID:{Insert random alphanumeric string}
```

Payload:

```
<OFX>
    <SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
        <SONRQ>
            <DTCLIENT>20180108012004
            <USERID>{Insert user id}
            <USERPASS>{Insert password}
            <LANGUAGE>ENG
            <FI>
                <ORG>B1     # Comes from ofxhome.com 
                <FID>10898
            </FI>
            <APPID>QWIN
            <APPVER>1800
            <CLIENTUID>{Insert random alphanumeric string}
        </SONRQ>
    </SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
    <CREDITCARDMSGSRQV1>
        <CCSTMTTRNRQ>
            <TRNUID>{Insert random alphanumeric string}
            <CLTCOOKIE>4
            <CCSTMTRQ>
                <CCACCTFROM>
                    <ACCTID>{Insert account id here}
                </CCACCTFROM>
                <INCTRAN>
                    <DTSTART>20171208
                    <INCLUDE>Y
                </INCTRAN>
            </CCSTMTRQ>
        </CCSTMTTRNRQ>
    </CREDITCARDMSGSRQV1>
</OFX>
```

4. Verify the request 
   You will get a response that says,
   "Please verify your identity within the next 7 days. Using your desktop computer, go to your bank's website and visit the Secure Message Center for instructions." After a small delay (in minutes), you will receive a message in your Secure Message Center asking to confirm that you made this request. Confirm the request. This response and verification happens with each new Client UID you submit.
5. Make the OFX request again, and you should receive your transactions!

### Comments

Many thanks to Harry Sit @ thefinancebuff.com for doing most of the work!!

More is possible through OFX, it's a complicated standard. Look to the specification for details.

You can also use GnuCash to see other promising settings.

This is using OFX 1.02, but Chase is now at 2.2

### References

https://thefinancebuff.com/replacing-microsoft-money-part-5-ofx-scripts.html#comments

http://www.ofx.net/

http://www.ofxhome.com/

http://www.ofxhome.com/ofxforum/viewtopic.php?id=47456

https://rhye.org/post/parsing-ofx-leex/

Comment: I was able to make REST API calls to make this work, but after looking at the python library, I changed the request content type from `application/xml` (was giving me Error Code 500's) to `application/x-ofx` and it worked!

Comment: Slight clarification: "Headers" here are OFX Headers, which go in the body of the HTTP request, separated from the OFX request payload with a blank line.

Comment: As of 10/24/2019, the location of the described settings is a bit different: `Account > Profile & Settings > Account Safe > Desktop software > Next` and follow a little wizard.

Comment: Does this script still work? I am calling `ofx-ba-tfb.py chase my_chase_username` and then I get this error: `getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed` Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @kmoney12 that looks like an error with your environment, not the script. The script just makes a simple http connection to "https://ofx.chase.com." Can you connect to that address in your browser? Also, this SO question looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean

Comment: The enable desktop software has now been moved to chase website -> hamburger menu -> security and privacy -> desktop software

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for this gem! It is so crazy how hidden and poorly documented this OFX protocol is, and it has been quite frustrating to browse the rare resources online and get something working. Indeed, the key is to spoof Quicken, and I can confirm your approach and your script works as of today. Time to build something out of this now :D

Comment: Glad it helped, @SimonNinon! :)

Comment: When I click the link in Chase's message to verify my identity, it keeps loading. Does anyone has this issue?

Comment: Does anyone know if this works if you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your chase account?

Comment: This seemed to suddenly stop working. On the chase website -> hamburger menu -> security and privacy -> desktop software it says that chase is "Changing the way" the desktop apps authenticate. Does anyway one have an updated script?

Answer (score 3):

As HLE indicates, Chase has killed OFX/DirectConnect as of late Sept./early Oct. 2022. Here are some related articles:

"As of October 6th, 2022, Chase will no longer be supporting Direct Connect/OFX which includes 3rd-party bill pay. Along with some of the other larger financial institutions, Chase has moved to the Open Banking connection method for transaction importing. A link to an article that explains what Open Banking is all about is listed below."
https://www.banktivity.com/support/articles/banktivity-7/ofx-direct-connect-will-no-longer-be-supported-by-chase-as-of-october-6th-2022/

"Chase Bank is changing the way it connects with personal finance management solutions like Quicken. To keep Quicken connected to your Chase account you'll need to switch you connection method on or before September 26, 2022."
https://community.quicken.com/discussion/7916266/quicken-chase-announce-killing-link-to-chase-direct-connect-bill-pay

**Possible solutions for Moneydance users:**

http://infinitekind.tenderapp.com/discussions/online-banking/23881-chase-bank-accounts-no-longer-can-connect

It sounds like .QXF files contain the same/similar data as .OFX files and the downloading of such files may be scriptable. I will update this answer if I find out more.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Any thoughts on how this would work for `beancount` users? I arrived at this thread hoping to automate the download of OFX files for use with [`beancount-import`](https://github.com/jbms/beancount-import)

Answer (score 2):

since October 5, 2022, Chase disconnected ofx.chase.com and look like you have to go aggregators like Quicken/MD+ to get your data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).