# python https authentication error?

Tags: python, https, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to print time data from this site: clockofeidolon.com and I found that the hour, minutes and seconds are stored in "span class="big-**x**"
tags and have tried to get the data with this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session

session = Session()
session.headers['user-agent'] = (
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/'
    '66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
)

url = 'https://clockofeidolon'
response = session.get(url=url)

data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
spans = soup.find('<span class="big')
print(data)
print([span.text for span in spans])
```

I keep getting authentication erros though

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: `https://clockofeidolon` is not a valid URL.Make it `https://clockofeidolon.com`

Comment: Oh wow I feel dumb but thank you still!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host `clockofeidolon` did not resolve to an IP.  You were probably looking for `clockofeidolon.com`.

Answer (score 1):

This error is occuring because you are trying to access an URL that doesn't exist (`https://clockofeidolon`) or Python can't reach.

Look at this question, which explains what that error means:

["getaddrinfo failed", what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean)