# socket programming with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

> I have a problem with this code, please help me solve it    this code
>   is giving give me the following error:
>   socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

```
 import socket
 servername='host'
 serverport=12000
 clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 message=input('input:')
 clientsocket.sendto(message.encode('ascii'),(servername,serverport))
 modimess,serveraddress=clientsocket.recvfrom(2048)
 print(modimess)
 clientsocket.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["getaddrinfo failed", what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: Could post the full stacktrace of your error?

Comment: What's the problem with the code above?