# update data of arcgis app with python arcgis api

Tags: python, arcgis, arcgis-online

I created an web app in ArcGIS Online (map journal). I want to update the underlying data of the map journal (e.g. text) as a step in an automation workflow. However, i am unable to update the data. I isolated the problem to the following code:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

# Login
arcgis_username = ""
arcgis_password = ""

gis = GIS("http://rhk.maps.arcgis.com", arcgis_username, arcgis_password)

# item is a map journal app
item = gis.content.get("6116f1493f214bed8018a4e62e4a8324")

item_data = item.get_data()
item.update(data=item_data)
```

when i try to run this code i get an error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\iReportAutomation\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I think a don't use the update function in a proper way. What am I doing wrong? And how can I update the data of an arcgis online app?

Comment: `getaddrinfo failed` means that Python cannot see `http://rhk.maps.arcgis.com`. You'll need to fix your networking so that your machine can see `rhk.maps.arcgis.com`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335972/720773 for a little more information.