# I'm trying to read the IP address for a domain name with Python and I'm getting strange errors I don't quite understand

Tags: python, ip-address

When I run this bit of code:

```
import socket

domainName = 'test.domain.io'

old_ip = socket.gethostbyname(domainName)

print(old_ip)
```

I get this error in PyCharm:
"File "C:/Users/UserName/PycharmProjects/AddyGet/ThingstoTry.py", line 5, in 
old_ip = socket.gethostbyname(domainName)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed"

When I point the debugger at line 5, I see the following errors:

```
"ret.metadata= {NameError}name 'ret' is not defined"
"route53= {NameError}name 'route53' is not defined"
"zone= {NameError}name 'zone' is not defined"
"zone= {NameError}name 'zone' is not defined"
"route53.connection= {NameError}name 'route53' is not defined"
```

The domain is hosting on route53, but I'm not importing route53 because I didn't think I would need to just to retrieve an IP address. So, do I need to be importing route53 and working with route53 methods just to get this IP address? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Also worth mentioning, because it's a "socket.gaierror", I tried the solutions here:
["getaddrinfo failed", what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean)

I am not behind a firewall (I disabled Window's firewall). There are no proxy environmental variables by default on my system, and putting myself behind a proxy also didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, running the code example, I get output `23.221.222.250`.

It might not be a Python issue, but more an OS issue. What happens if you open a Windows `cmd` prompt and type:

```
ping test.domain.io
```

Here's my output (repetition and stats edited out):

```
Pinging test.domain.io [23.221.222.250] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 23.221.222.250: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=47
...
```

Comment: It says "Ping request could not find test.domain.io". Please check name and try again.

Comment: OK. Then this is clearly an OS (network setup) issue, not Python, since it seems that `test.domain.io` is a valid DNS name with a valid IP address. Oh, I'll mention this in the answer, too, but I ran your code example, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Okay, so the next step would be connecting to a different network?

Comment: Are you using this website on the same computer? It might be that you have a faulty DNS server in your network. What does `ping www.stackoverflow.com` do?

Comment: Gives me this:
Pinging stackoverflow.com [151.101.193.69] with 32 bytes of data:     
Reply from 151.101.193.69: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=58     and etc.

Comment: Well, that's odd. It could be a custom entry in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host. See https://superuser.com/q/1019467/1274805 for advice from the pros.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'll check that out!