# Issue in pip install command

Tags: pip

Please help me in fixing the below command

pip install GitPython

```
Error:

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifoedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',) ': /simple/gitpython

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement GitPython (from versions :) 
No matching distribution found for GitPython
```

Comment: Version is Python  3

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["getaddrinfo failed", what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean)