# Why am I getting [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed when retrieving from config?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser, imaplib

I'm using ConfigParser to pull IMAP details for email login which works fine on Linux, however I keep getting `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed` when running on Windows. I'm using Python 3.8.

This is the code causing the error.

```
self._config = configparser.ConfigParser()
self._config.read('config.ini')
self._mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self._config.get('imap', 'host'),993) # <- the error
```

I thought it may have been a race condition, the class initializing before ConfigParser was able to initialize properly however adding a print in there to read out the host worked fine. Pasting the actual imap url string in place of the `self._config.get` works

Comment: The ```getaddrinfo``` error relates to your host name.  Is it an IP or an actual host name?  The system can't seem to find that address..  take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean

Comment: @ewong It is a hostname. When I put the string in manually it works fine, but not with ConfigParser

Comment: what does ```self._config.get('imap', 'host')``` return?   What does your config look like?   I'm somewhat guessing it's falling back on ```host``` as it can't find ```imap``` mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Im nut sure but i think you should setup ajson configfile then save the hoststring into a variable that you then use to connect. The final code then would look something like this:

```
import json
with open("config.json", "r+") as conf: # open in readmode and create the file if not exists
  config = json.load(conf)
  host = config.get("host")
```

The json file then would look like this:

```
{
  "host": "IP_Adress"
}
```

Edit:
To check if it worked you can print out the host variable. this should print the value of "host" within the config.json

```
print(host)
```

Comment: I'm currently using ConfigParser, wasn't planning to use JSON. If this is the only way to make it work, I'll circle back to it