# Python requests error: for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am blanking on how to debug this and can't find anything on the Internet.
I want to make an API post call to the server.
I can see that it is mostly error no. 11001.
Let me know if any other details needed to debug this.

P.S.- How to debug errors in general? Google?

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'authorization': <token>,
}

files = {
    'source': open('ilo5.zip', 'rb'),
    'metadata': open('metadata.json', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.post('https://<blablah>:443/stross/initiateScan', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
print("hi")
```

These are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn        
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen      
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022FD119A350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen      
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment        
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<blablah>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stross/initiateScan (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022FD119A350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bose\Desktop\stross\stross-api-call.py", line 12, in <module>
    response = requests.post('<blablah>:443/stross/initiateScan', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bose\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<blablah>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stross/initiateScan (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022FD119A350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

edit.
new code.

```
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

proxies = {
   'http': 'http://<>.net:8080',
   'https': 'http://<>.net:8080',
}

headers = {
    'authorization': <token>,
}

files = {
    'source': open('ilo5.zip', 'rb'),
    'metadata': open('metadata.json', 'rb'),
}
response = requests.post('https://<>.net:443/stross/initiateScan', headers=headers, 
files=files, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
print("hi. Response Status Code:",response.status_code)
```

I was getting:

> InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
> InsecureRequestWarning)

but upon disabling the warnings, I am getting no output, i.e.- it is running without any output.
Please help.

Comment: In `requests.post('https://<blablah>:443/....`  is <blablah> just a placeholder or what you are trying to connect to? I ask because in the error log it says you are trying to connect to that `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<blablah>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stross/initiateScan....`

Comment: @kconsiglio i am trying to connect to the server of this internal static analysis tool that my company uses. Does that help?

Comment: It's possible the hostname isn't being resolved. Are you sure there aren't any typos in the url? Are you able to navigate to the same url in the browser? Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335972/20473839) to see if the address is able to be resolved. Replacing localhost in the example with the hostname and port you want like "google.com" without the "https://"

Comment: @kconsiglio you were right! I was missing a hyphen in the url. But I am running into new errors now.

Comment: Are you saying `print("hi. Response Status Code:",response.status_code)` is not printing out anything? Setting `verify=False ` like you have is correct to ignore SSL errors, so not sure why it would not work.

Comment: That's right. `print("hi. Response Status Code:",response.status_code)`  is not printing out anything.

Comment: When you set your proxies you have `https': 'http://<>.net:8080',` for the https proxy but your url is "http" not https". To clarify your print statement is also not printing out the "hi..." part? If that is true than your request is just hanging. try passing a timeout value in your `requests.post(....)` something like `timeout=5` to timeout after 5 seconds.