# Seleniun Webdriver Failed to establish a new connection

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Been knocking my head around persistent problems with trying to get Selenium Web Driver up and running. The following code is what I have. Also sent it to friends and they've been able to run it after installing the mandatory selenium & webdriver-manager files (Same ones I am using).

Seems like this is some kind of networking issue? I've searched round but stuck with limited to zero understanding of networking to make any progress with this issue. I have included the full error log below.
If there is anything else I can add let me know.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import  Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
#options.add_experimental_option("detact", True)

#crashes here on next line
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Error Log:

```
File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 174, in _new_conn conn = connection.create_connection( File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
line 72, in create_connection for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host,
port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM): File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\socket.py", line 953,
in getaddrinfo for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family,
type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 703, in urlopen httplib_response = self._make_request( File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 386, in _make_request self._validate_conn(conn) File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 1040, in _validate_conn conn.connect() File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 358, in connect self.sock = conn = self._new_conn() File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
line 186, in _new_conn raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023F38A7D7C0>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
line 489, in send resp = conn.urlopen( File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
line 785, in urlopen retries = retries.increment( File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
line 592, in increment raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or
ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_114.0.5735
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
object at 0x0000023F38A7D7C0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
line 59, in request return session.request(method=method, url=url,
**kwargs) File "C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
line 587, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
line 701, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) File
"C:\dev\devtools\apps\python3\python-3.9.0\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
line 565, in send raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_114.0.5735
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
object at 0x0000023F38A7D7C0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any advice appreciated, thank you.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean sounds like you might be using a proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `selenium` `4.10.0` or newer, then the driver manager is already included. This code will handle that, and be compatible with any platform:

```py
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
if "linux" in sys.platform:
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"],
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that super clear where you are exactly stuck. However on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) box with [python](/questions/tagged/python) ***v3.9.0***, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.8.0*** and [WebDriverManager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) ***v3.5.2*** the below program executes just perfecto:

- Code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  import sys

  print ("Python Version: " +sys.version)
  import webdriver_manager
  print("WebDriverManager version: " +webdriver_manager.__version__)
  import selenium
  print("Selenium version: " +selenium.__version__)
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
  driver.get('https://pypi.org/')
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  Python Version: 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
  WebDriverManager version: 3.5.2
  Selenium version: 4.8.0


  ====== WebDriver manager ======
  Current google-chrome version is 114.0.5735
  Get LATEST chromedriver version for 114.0.5735 google-chrome
  Driver [C:\Users\fnmae.lname\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\114.0.5735.90\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
  ```

Comment: Hey, output;

"webdriver version = 3.7.0" / 
"selenium version = 4.1.2"

Crashed at same line: driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options) once more with the exact same error as above.

Perhaps version issue or?